# mysqli warnings appearing when creating dynamic WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to create a query with a dynamic where clause. The query has a default where clause where it will always check for `SessionId = ?` no matter which option is chosen from the `students and`questions` drop down menu.

Then I have a php code where if the user has selected an individual student or an individual question (or in other words has not selected the option `All` in the `student drop down menu or the user has not selected`All`in the question drop down menu). If the`All` option is selected in either of the 2 drop down menus then it does not add those parameters to the WHERE clause.

Anyway when trying to do this, I am getting these errors:

```
Warning: mysqli::prepare(): (42000/1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE q.SessionId = ?' at line 15 in ... on line 320 

Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in ... on line 322
```

My question is what do I need to sort out in the mysqli and php code below in order to fix the errors?

Below is the code with comments to display line numbers where errors are:

```
$selectedstudentanswerqry = "
SELECT
StudentAlias, StudentForename, StudentSurname, q.SessionId, QuestionNo, QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT Answer
ORDER BY Answer SEPARATOR ',' ) AS Answer, r.ReplyType, QuestionMarks, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT StudentAnswer ORDER BY StudentAnswer SEPARATOR ',') AS StudentAnswer, ResponseTime, MouseClick, StudentMark
FROM Student s
INNER JOIN Student_Answer sa ON (s.StudentId = sa.StudentId)
INNER JOIN Student_Response sr ON (sa.StudentId = sr.StudentId)
INNER JOIN Question q ON (sa.QuestionId = q.QuestionId)
INNER JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
LEFT JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId
LEFT JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId
";

// Initially empty
$where = array('q.SessionId = ?');
$parameters = array($_POST["session"]);
$parameterTypes = 'i';

// Check whether a specific student was selected
if($_POST["student"] !== 'All') {
    $where[] = 'sa.StudentId = ?';
    $parameters[] = $_POST["student"];
    $parameterTypes .= 'i';
}

// Check whether a specific question was selected
// NB: This is not an else if!
if($_POST["question"] !== 'All') {
    $where[] = 'q.QuestionId = ?';
    $parameters[] = $_POST["question"];
    $parameterTypes .= 'i';
}

$selectedstudentanswerqry .= "
GROUP BY sa.StudentId, q.QuestionId
ORDER BY StudentAlias, q.SessionId, QuestionNo
";

// If we added to $where in any of the conditionals, we need a WHERE clause in
// our query
if(!empty($where)) {
    $selectedstudentanswerqry .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
    global $mysqli;
    $selectedstudentanswerstmt=$mysqli->prepare($selectedstudentanswerqry); //line 320 error
    // You only need to call bind_param once
    $selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_param($parameterTypes,implode($parameters)); //line 322 error
}




// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
$selectedstudentanswerstmt->execute(); 
$selectedstudentanswerstmt->bind_result($detailsStudentAlias,$detailsStudentForename,$detailsStudentSurname,$detailsSessionId,$detailsQuestionNo, 
$detailsQuestonContent,$detailsOptionType,$detailsNoofAnswers,$detailsAnswer,$detailsReplyType,$detailsQuestionMarks,$detailsStudentAnswer,$detailsResponseTime,
$detailsMouseClick,$detailsStudentMark);
$selectedstudentanswerstmt->store_result();
$selectedstudentanswernum = $selectedstudentanswerstmt->num_rows();
```

Comment: echo $selectedstudentanswerqry after you finish building it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your doing your GROUP BY and ORDER BY before you WHERE statement.

Try put these lines,

```
$selectedstudentanswerqry .= "
  GROUP BY sa.StudentId, q.QuestionId
  ORDER BY StudentAlias, q.SessionId, QuestionNo
";
```

After your if statement,

```
if(!empty($where)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Also the value of $selectedstudentanswerqry at the end would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

echo the query your `WHERE` is not in proper place it is before `GROUP BY`